# Git - sync Github with Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, synchronization

I have Azure DevOps repo and its copy on Github (`secondary`). I have written pipeline to sync Github repo with Azure repo after any push in any branch:

```
trigger:
  - '*'
pool: MyPool
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $stageDir = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" | Split-Path
      $githubDir = "${stageDir}/gitHub"
      $destination = "${githubDir}/${repoName}.git"
      $sourceURL = "https://$(AzureDevOps.PAT)@dev.azure.com/${azureOrganization}/${repoName}/_git/${repoName}"
      $destURL = "https://${githubUsername}:$(Github.PAT)@github.com/${githubUsername}/${repoName}.git"
      
      if((Test-Path -path $githubDir))
      {
        Remove-Item -Path $githubDir -Recurse -force
      }
      
      if(!(Test-Path -path $githubDir))
      {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $githubDir
        Set-Location $githubDir
        git clone --mirror $sourceURL
      }
      Set-Location $destination
      
      git remote rm secondary
      git remote add --mirror=fetch secondary $destURL
      git remote prune $sourceUrl    <---- added
      git fetch $sourceURL
      git push secondary --all

      git branch -lvv | grep -v "main" | grep ": gone]" | grep -v "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -d    <---- added

      Set-Location $stageDir
      if((Test-Path -path $githubDir))
      {
        Remove-Item -Path $githubDir -Recurse -force
      }
```

This script works fine with pushing changes and new branches to Azure. But it doesn't work if I remove some branch in Azure - Github will still has deleted branch.

I have found that removing outdated branches can be performed by `git fetch --prune $sourceURL` but it didn't work in this case.

Is it possible to somehow synchronize these repositories for the case of outdated branches?

**EDIT:** I have edited my code (marked as <---- added). It works fine in case of Azure + localhost but when I try to check it in case of Azure + Github it doesn't. What's wrong with it?

Comment: `git fetch --prune` removes the **remote tracking** branch.

Comment: @Daniel Mann Is Github repo considered as local to Azure repo?

Comment: Branches in your *clone* of the repo in your pipeline would be considered local branches, yes.

Comment: You probably want `git push --mirror`, which ends with delete requests for un-pushed branch and tag names. *Be careful* with this! There's also `--prune` for `git push --all`; again, be careful with this.

Comment: @torek From git documentation for `git push --prune`: "Remove **remote** branches that don’t have a local counterpart.". I need an inverse effect - Remove **local** branches that don’t have a remote counterpart.

Comment: @Egor: Ah, I see. But you ran `git clone --mirror`: you have exactly the same set of branches as `origin`. If you want to subsequently remove any branch names that don't exist on some non-`origin` repo, you'll need to do that manually. (Or—though this is probably *more* complicated—you could get a list of references you want to keep and run your `git clone` manually as `git init` and then `git remote add` if desired, and then a `git fetch` with a series of explicit refspecs.)

Comment: I've changed a code according to deleting local branches. But it's still not working.